# viewing coredata with sqlite browser in xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

Since upgrading to XCode 5, I am unable to view data in the sqlite file in my Applications Folder. The folder structure has changed somewhat but I can still find the correct App but when I open the sqlite file with the sqlite browser there does not appear to be any data in CoreData.
Any ideas?

Comment: amazing how an app like Xcode is still unable to browse, create or populate coredata databases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest you to use [CoreDataPro](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility) app for viewing your CoreData storage.
My [fork](https://github.com/soxjke/CoreDataUtility) has minor improvement - alphabetical ordering of Simulator managed object models.

Comment: Very useful thank you. Still confused with what the issue was around sqlite browser though.

Answer (score 11):

In iOS 7 SQLite's [Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html) is turned on by default. In this mode data is split into three files (.sqlite, .sqlite-shm, .sqlite-wal). I've seen that some SQLite viewers ignore .sqlite-shm and .sqlite-wal files, thus not showing proper data.

Comment: Can you please suggest some way to fix this.

Comment: @Gypsa: I use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). It's not the best software, but it's free and it does its job.

Comment: i am also using SQLite Manager but still i can't see the expected data?? I do see the 3 files and .sqlite-shm .sqlite-wal are the ones changing if i add data to the app. Any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

I'm using **SQLite Manager** plugin in Firefox, it works pretty decent.

You can get the plugin here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

After you install the plugin you will see 'SQLite Manager' (with a database icon in blue color) item in Tools menu.

Comment: I used to do this to view sqlite data, but now I am enable to do that. Not sure why. I tested this by downloading some tutorial code for core data, in that this technique worked. But If i create the new project (My xcode 6.3.2 version) and do that tutorial manually than I am not able to see the result in Sqlite manager plugin