# Where is my database data (Core Data, iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, core-data

I'm using a sqlite database to store the data for my iPhone app. I know that the location for this sqlite-file is in Users/Leontien/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/4ACB095B-D6B7-488F-AB18-27800A3386E4/Documents.

When I start the app I can create some database objects. I can see the created objects in a tableview. When I stop and start my app, it shows the list with already created objects. So I know my data is stored somewhere.

When I open the sqlite-file in the path mentioned above, SQLite Database Browser shows a completely empty database (no tables present). This is not what I expected...

Where can I find my database data?

I use the following code in AppDelegate.m for Core Data.

```
#pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    _managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"PetHealth.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I stop and start my app

Do you kill your app from the multitasking menu?

If yes, then see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100649/viewing-coredata-with-sqlite-browser-in-xcode-5/19111789#19111789). It may be the cause of your problem. [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) is free and works fine with iOS 7 projects. [SimPholders app](http://simpholders.com/) may also be of help here.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the data with SQLite Manager. One extra question: The data is in the hidden folder Library. I can see this folder in Finder, but not when I select a file in SQLite Manager. Is there a way to change this? Now I copied the files before viewing them...

Comment: sqlite data browser stopped displaying data for me, but SQLite Manager works great.

Answer (score 0):

When you create NSManagedObjects you call SAVE method in ManagedObjectContext?

If you has the CoreDat stack in AppDelegate try this:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

NSError* error = nil;
[appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error] // Save the Context (Commit)
```

If you know that try to use MesaSQLite Mac Application

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are in the wrong directory and looking at the wrong version of your database. You will have several apps in your simulator if you change the bundle identifier, and you will have one for each iOS version you use in Simulator.

Try listing all the apps for a giving iOS Version that are installed in the Simulator like this:

```
cd /Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.1/Applications
ls -d */*.app
```

You can now verify the correct path. Repeat the same for iOS 7 by substituting `7.0` for `6.1` above.

Also, do not forget to call `[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]` to persist your changes, but after what you describe you should already be doing that.