# Mac OS X how to query Core Data (SQLite) data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, xcode5

I'm working on app using Core Data and I'm trying to verify the creation of the data on my core data files. I tried SQLite Profesional, I open the myApp.sqlite with SQLite Profesional and I only see the schema. There is another to files on that directory:

myApp.sqlite-shm
myApp.sqlite-wal

My question is how I verify the data I'm creating on Core Data with my app in the SQLite files there is a tool I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [viewing coredata with sqlite browser in xcode 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100649/viewing-coredata-with-sqlite-browser-in-xcode-5)

Comment: Your data is probably in the Write Ahead Log (the WAL file). Set the JOURNAL=DELETE option when you open the Core Data store in your app and it won't use WAL mode.

Comment: There’s also [Liya](http://cutedgesystems.com/software/Liya/) for free.

Answer (score 1):

The data should be in that sqlite file. For OS X SQLite viewer, I recommend [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/).
Or you can view the files in Core Data way using [CoreDataPro](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility).

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling save: on your managed object context? If not, your data will not have been persisted to disk yet.