# Unable to see records in sqlite file which is generated using coredata

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm using coredata in my iOS app. I'm able to save and retrieve data through the app even after terminating and relaunching it. I could see .sqlite file in document directory as well. But when I open that .sqlite file using Firefox's SQLite Manager I'm not able to see any records in the tables.

Comment: There is some encoding, because of which firefox sqlite manager is unable to show you the core data result. This method used to work previuosly but now it dosent

Comment: Is it.. Any alternative to see the data in sqlite file?

Comment: Please look at some reference links in answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. [viewing coredata with sqlite browser in xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100649/viewing-coredata-with-sqlite-browser-in-xcode-5)

I have not tried this but if you want to https://www.codefellows.org/blog/core-data-and-database-browser-for-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

one copy of .sqlite file store in your local device database that contain your User data and your project sqlite file only providing structure of your database.

i.e

/Users/"Yourusername"/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/50923155-3C1A-4071-B2A9-94D11CDD7678/data/Containers/Data/Application/856BA865-0EA8-486A-A9B1-5A5E51005966/Documents/"sqlitefile name"